# How can I show last 100 rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use this query to show results from MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
ORDER BY id ASC
```

But I want to show only the last 100 rows. How can I make it?

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100
```

But it shows the first 100 rows, I need the last 100 rows...

Can you help me with this?

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC
```

This will select the last 100 rows from table, and then order them in ascending order.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `order by id asc` with `order by id desc` to change the sorting order from ascending to descending and get *last* 100 rows.

Comment: I try with order by DESC, but the problem is that now they show me from top to the bottom, if make them with DESC, it show me from bottom to the top... i don't want like this...

Comment: @tyrlaka: then try with Nico's solution.